# The probability that exactly two balls are common to both the draws is:

Tags: probability

> A bag has 10 balls. Six balls are drawn in an attempt and replaced.
>   Then another draw of 5 balls is made from the bag. The probability
>   that exactly two balls are common to both the draws is:
>
> a) $5/21$
>
> b) $2/21$
>
> c) $7/21$
>
> d) $3/21$

Attempt:

Total number of draws is: $^{10}C_6 \times {^{10}}C_5$

Number of favourable draws is: $^{6}C_2 \times {^{4}}C_3$

So $P(E) = \dfrac{^{6}C_2 \times {^{4}}C_3}{^{10}C_6 \times {^{10}}C_5} $

But it doesn't evaluate to any of the options above.

What's my mistake?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colour the six balls drawn in the first round red, the other four blue.

You then seek the probability that you draw exactly two red and three blue
balls in the second round. The number of possible draws is $\binom{10}5$
and the number of favourable draws is $\binom62\binom43$.

Comment: But I dont get why we arent including the initial draw's state in the total number of draws/

Comment: @Abcd So this evaluates to $\dfrac{{^6}C_2 \times {^4}C_3}{{^{10}}C_5}$ in your notation.

Comment: @Abcd Divide $\binom{10}6\binom 62\binom43$ by $\binom{10}6\binom{10}5$ if you like.

Comment: @Abcd The initial draw only serves to determine the division of repeat balls and new balls.So it only matters we drew $6$.